# Native Lazy Loading on Safari

Tags: performance

Wordpress 5.5 was released and native Native Lazyload has been added by default to Wordpress.

As you might know, Safari doesn't support this feature.

Any idea of how to make it work with safari? I tried using this polyfill but it didn't work. https://github.com/mfranzke/loading-attribute-polyfill

Any help will be appreciated